# Can a name refer to both a template and a value?

Tags: c++

I'd like to be able to call a wait function with an expression that states an amount of time, using either a template argument or a function argument to specify the amount of time to wait. (For added fun: these declarations are all inside a class template, so full specialization is not allowed.) My preference would be

```
wait< ms< 10 >>();
wait( 10 * ms );
```

but I'd settle for

```
wait< ms< 10 >>();
wait( ms( 10 ));
```

I can make a wait function template that accepts either a template argument or a function argument, but for the argument I am stuck. ms< 10 > must be a type, not a built-in, something like

```
template< int n >
struct ms {
   typedef void this_is_a_duration;
   constexpr int amount = n;
};
```

so I can do compile time 'type-cheking' for the presence of this_is_a_duration. But that seems to rule out that ms or ms() is anything but a type, right? And there seems to be now way to make ( 10 * ms ) a valid expression when ms is a type? (A static conversion function would do it, if such were allowed..)

Is there any way I can make ms<10> be a type and ms or ms(10) be an expression?

Comment: Any particular reason you want that syntax? You can already do `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));`.

Comment: Soon enough, that'll be `10ms` as well.

Comment: @chris And it will be awesome.

Comment: @Joseph: this is for small microcontrollers, think 8kb code space. For instance, in suitable circumstances sleep< ns< 10 >>() must result in 1 instruction (a NOP).

Answer (score 0):

No, within the same lookup context, a name can only be one of a function, variable, or type (including the template forms of each). What you want to do is not possible.

The thing I would recommend is a one-letter namespace for one of the two:

```
wait<s::ms<10>>();
```

Comment: I realized that is a way out, but it feels so damn ugly. The user would have to remember two namespace names :( (Or one + which version requires it, which is probably wores.)

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest I can imagine:

```
#include <iostream>

struct ms {
    unsigned value;
    ms(unsigned value)
    :   value(value)
    {}
};

template <unsigned N, typename Unit>
void wait()  {
    std::cout << "Template\n";
}

void wait(const ms&) {
    std::cout << "No Template\n";
}

int main() {
    wait<10, ms>();
    wait(ms(10));
    return 0;
}
```